# How to check if a docx or doc file is empty

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a script that can convert a docx file to a json and I was wondering how can I detect if a file is empty.
A solution I found is that one:
https://thispointer.com/python-three-ways-to-check-if-a-file-is-empty/

Using:

- os.stat(file_path).st_size == 0:
- os.path.exists(file_path)
- os.path.getsize(path)

Unfortunately since an empty docx is not equal to 0. I can't use those methods.
Any other solution?

Comment: Did you find out how to read a doc/x file in python? Parse an empty file and inspect the parsed object to see what it contains (or doesn't contain). Then do the same for a non-empty file. Now you know how to check if it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

what if you use the docx module?

you can check it [here](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-ms-word-files-in-python-via-python-docx-module/), according to that documentation, you can read the paragraphs and after check the length:

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document("E:/my_word_file.docx")
all_paras = doc.paragraphs
len(all_paras)
```

If the lenght is equal to 0 you can assume this is empty.
However this only works for .docx files for what I can see

Comment: On my side en empty file has at least a Len(all_paras) = 1, so I don't think it would work.

Comment: well, I think you can take that first paragraph and see if that is an empty paragraph. there might be a better solution tho